# Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys // ). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: reactjs, react-state

> state={
> api_data:[ ],
> status:false
> }
> fetch(my_url)
> .then(res => res.json())
> .then((resp) => {
> this.setState({
> status: true,
> api_data:[...this.state.api_data,**{short_link:resp.result.short_link,orginal:false}** ]
> })
> })

Comment: Could you reformat this code so it is easier to read?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.